# Openstack horizon not accessible after installation through conjure-up

Tags: juju, openstack, lxc, conjure-up

I have managed to get openstack installed using conjure-up. I followed the below steps for the installation
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo snap install lxd; sudo snap install conjure-up --classic; /snap/bin/lxd init --auto; /snap/bin/lxc network create lxbr0 ipv4.address=auto ipv4.nat=true ipv6.address=none ipv6.nat=false;conjure-up openstack

[conjure-up  post installation summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tcfJ.jpg)

When i try to access http://10.40.201.178/horizon  nothing happens. I'm getting the error

This site can’t be reached

10.40.201.178 took too long to respond.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer since I was able to resolve it using the following command
juju expose openstack-dashboard